# Split the \@authors list at \and

Tags: titles, conditionals, counters, xparse

With `xparse` it's pretty easy to split a list at each occurrence of a token. In my MWE I set up a new command `\mylist` in which I passes two names separated by `\and`. The `xparse` script splits the list at the `\and` token and outputs the two names under each other.

Is there a possibility to use this script with the `\@author` macro. I'd like to print the authors passed to `\author{}` one after the other in the `\maketitle` command. To make sure that LaTeX can normally use the author-command where I used to, I don't want to use the example code (underneath the MWE).

---

#### MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\NewDocumentCommand\mylist{>{\SplitList{\and}}m}
    {
    \ProcessList{#1}{\insertitem}
    }
\newcommand\insertitem[1]{#1\\}

\begin{document}

\noindent \emph{Authors:}\\
\mylist{John Doe \and Jane Doe}

\end{document}
```

---

#### Author Example

```
...
\RenewDocumentCommand\author{>{\SplitList{\and}}m}
...
\author{John Doe \and Jane Doe}
...
```

---

#### Count

I have set up a counter and add `1` for every item, so at the end I know how many authors were passed to the list. I then check with a conditional if the value of the counter is greater than 1. With this I could decide if `Author` or `Authors` should be output before the names. This does not work at the moment because I need the result *before* the array is defined. If I could use the default LaTeX `\author` command, this problem would not occur, because the `\author` command is populated in the preamble. Then the `\maketitle` shoulr prints out the authors as shown in the MWE.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\RenewDocumentCommand\author{>{\SplitList{\and}}m}
    {
    \ProcessList{#1}{\insertitem}
    }

\newcounter{numberOfAuthors}

\newcommand\insertitem[1]{%
    #1%
    \newline%
    \addtocounter{numberOfAuthors}{1}
}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\checkIfGreatherThan{%
    \ifnum\c@numberOfAuthors>1
        \noindent There are \thenumberOfAuthors\ authors given. The output should be \emph{Authors:}
    \else 
        \noindent There is only one author given. The output should be \emph{Author:}
  \fi}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\noindent \emph{Authors:}\\
% uncomment one of the two commands to test
% \author{John Doe \and Jane Doe}
% \author{John Doe}

\checkIfGreatherThan

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since both `\author` and `\@author` are macros that are 'volatile', i.e. `\let` to `\relax` after usage of `\maketitle`, it is better to store the content of the argument of `\author` to another macro, which is evaluated later on.

The `\and` macro is 'complicated' in the sense that it is actually closing a `tabular` environment and starting another one. I decided to redefine `\and` to expand to `,` and use the `expl3` macro `\seq_set_from_clist:Nx` in order to split the list into the individual names.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}



\ExplSyntaxOn

\cs_generate_variant:Nn \seq_set_from_clist:Nn {No,Nx}

\NewDocumentCommand{\myinternalsplitter}{m}{%
  \group_begin:
  \seq_set_from_clist:Nx \l_tmpa_seq {#1}% Split the expanded list, i.e. `\and` will place `,` 
  \int_compare:nNnTF { \seq_count:N \l_tmpa_seq } = {1} {% Count the number of items
    \displayauthorhead
  }{
    \displayauthorshead
  }
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \l_tmpa_seq {\insertitem{##1}}% Display the list with `\insertitem
  \group_end:
}

\ExplSyntaxOff


\makeatletter

\let\latex@@author\author

\RenewDocumentCommand{\author}{m}{%
  \latex@@author{#1}% Use the old command
  \gdef\@@authorlist{#1}%
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\displayauthorhead}{}{%
  Author: 

}

\NewDocumentCommand{\displayauthorshead}{}{%
  Authors:

}


\NewDocumentCommand\mylist{}{%
  \begingroup
  \def\and{,}
  \edef\@authorlist{\@@authorlist}
  \myinternalsplitter{\@authorlist}
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother

\newcommand\insertitem[1]{%
  #1

}


\author{John Doe \and Jane Doe \and John Hannibal Smith \and B.A. Baracus}

\begin{document}
\title{Foo}

\mylist%


\maketitle


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Wow, that's awesome! Thank you very much Christian! I still have a little question. How can I align the output to the right? I tried with `\begin{flushright}` and with a right-aligned `tabularx` environment, but neither of them worked. Thank you very much in advance! PS: I need your code for the `\author` command and for a self defined `\supervisor` command. The authors should be left aligned and the supervisors right aligned, so the alignment shouldn't be hard coded to the script. It would be better if the output would respect the `flushright` environment.

Comment: @Sam: I'll check later on... I have no time right now ...

Comment: No problem, take your time :)

Comment: I solved the issue myself. While cleaning up my code I removed your empty lines in `\NewDocumentCommand{\displayauthorhead}`, `\NewDocumentCommand{\displayauthorshead}` and `\newcommand\insertitem` and replaced it by `\newline`. I now reverted it back to the empty line and it works fine. Is there a more clean solution than an empty line? I tried with `\\` which resulted in over 100 errors in my case...

Comment: All fine, `\linebreak` did the job.

Comment: @Sam: `\newline` and `\linebreak` are means of last resort only. An empty line is the correct trigger for TeX to ship out a new paragraph

Answer (score 0):

As you linked this question in [another one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/391048/get-number-of-authors-in-author/392541?noredirect=1#comment975306_392541) of yours with a similar scope you could use the same technique that I employed there to solve it (delimited arguments) as an alternative to `xparse`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\makeatletter
\newcounter{authors}
\stepcounter{authors}
\def\@author{\textit{Author\ifnum\theauthors>1s\fi:}\\}
\def\split@and#1\and#2{%
  \g@addto@macro\@author{#1\\}%
  \ifx#2\@nil\else
    \stepcounter{authors}%
    \expandafter\split@and\expandafter#2\fi
}
\def\author#1{\split@and#1\and\@nil}
\makeatother

\title{title}
\author{John Doe}%\and Jane Doe}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

[image: example1_compiled]

[image: example2_compiled]